# I loose a question

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I remember that I had  asked a  question about  obstructions for a  $n^2$  dimensional  vector  bundle  for  which the  fibers    admit  a  structure  of  matrix  algebra. I  do  not  remember  whether it was an independent  question or it was  included  in comments  in another  question.

I searched a lot  both in web and  in Mo  to find that  question  but  I  can not  find it. I remember  a  participant  says  that there  are obstructions as  Diximier  Duady  classes in 3th  cohohomology of the  base  space.

I  would  like  to read that  conversation as  a supplementary  to the  following  my  MO  question

[Parallel transport as algebra isomorphism](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266497/parallel-transport-as-algebra-isomorphism)

Can one  help  my to  find that  conversation?

Thank you very  much

Comment: I have tried searching using this SEDE query for the word
[Douady](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/615875/comments-containing-given-keyword-on-my-posts?Word=Douady&userid=36688) in comments on your posts. The only question if found was [Differential and pre-differential of Jacobi identity](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209694). (I did not find any mentioning Dixmier.) The same query [on math.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/615875/comments-containing-given-keyword-on-my-posts?Word=Douady&userid=143009) returns no results. (You can try other reasonable keywords.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  help.

Comment: But I guess that the question I linked to is not the one you are looking for, right?

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Yes  it  is  not but I thank  you  for  showing  me  the  explor data  search  system.  My  conversation was  about  obstructions  for fiberwise matrix  algebra  structure  for  a  vector  bundle.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  I remember  that  some  one  answered me  Duaddy Diximier  invariant  (Or  class)  or  some  thing  like this(In the  third  cohomology)

Comment: Are you sure it was spelled *Diximier* in those comments? (You have also used various spellings of Douady in your question and your comments here on meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Yes you are right. My  spelling was incorrect. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't help with finding the MO conversation, but indeed such bundles are governed by Dixmier-Douady characteristic classes in $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$. This is all discussed in Husemöller, Joachim, Jurco, Schottenloher "Basic Bundle Theory and K-Cohomology Invariants" (2008), more specifically in Chapter IV.

Comment: @July   I sincerely thank you very much for this reference.